# Docker python:alpineでcffiのコンパイルに失敗する

Tags: python, docker

`python:alpine`のDockerコンテナ上でアプリを動かしたいと考えているのですが、`pip install -r requirements.txt`内の`cffi`のインストール段階で以下のエラーが出て失敗します。

```
Collecting cffi==1.11.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading cffi-1.11.5.tar.gz (438kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

        No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
        the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
        the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
        to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
        tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
        -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
        Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
        the IRC channel #python on irc.freenode.net.)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-e8t2krwd/cffi/
```

Dockerfileは以下の通りです。

```
FROM python:alpine

ADD app.py /
ADD server.py /
ADD start.sh /
ADD requirements.txt /
ADD templates /

RUN apk add --no-cache git openssl ffmpeg opus libffi-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80 443
```

requirements.txtは以下の通りです。

```
aiohttp==1.0.5
async-timeout==2.0.1
certifi==2018.1.18
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
discord.py==0.16.12
Flask==0.12.2
get==0.0.39
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
multidict==4.1.0
post==0.0.26
public==0.0.65
pycparser==2.18
pydub==0.21.0
PyNaCl==1.0.1
query-string==0.0.28
requests==2.18.4
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.22
websockets==3.4
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

コンパイラが見つからないようですがなぜこうなってしまうのかわかりません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 解決法

`pip install` の前に以下を実行してください。

```
apk add build-base libffi-dev
```

### 解説

[cffi](http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) はその名の通り C への [FFI (Foreign Function Interface)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) を提供するものなので、動かすには C の処理系が必要です。そして `python:alpine` には GCC などの C コンパイラが含まれていません。したがって自前で [GCC](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/GCC) をインストールする必要があります。

また StackDestroyer さんの Dockerfile には既に含まれていますが、[公式のインストール手順](http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)によると GCC の他に [libffi-dev](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=libffi-dev&branch=edge) も必要です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事インストールできました。